# Differentiable and Integrable calculus terms

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas, ciencia

Is there a standard way to say "Differentiable" and "Integrable" in Spanish?

How would I say that a function is *differentiable* or *integrable*?

Comment: How would I say that a function is differentiable or integrable?

Answer (score 12):

As a former mathematician, yes.

Something is *diferenciable* or *derivable*. In Spanish, there's a distinction between those, but not in English.
*diferenciable* is used when talking about *multivariable calculus*; *derivable* is used when talking about *single variable calculus.*

As for *integrable*, it stays the same, namely:

> Sea *f* una función **integrable** en un subconjunto de los reales.

The spelling is kept, but the pronunciation obviously changes.